# mysqldump with ssh connection in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, mysql

I'm using a shell script that opens a ssh connection and creates an sqldump.

But, when I use `mysqldump` in the shell script it gives me the error:
"No such file or directory"

This is the line I use:

```
ssh user@host mysqldump -uusername -hlocalhost -ppassword --all-databases > /home/user/sqlfile.sql
```

The `mysqldump` works when i use it in an opened ssh connection or at the server in the commandline.

So my question is why do I get the error and why can't I run the mysqldump command in a shell script?

Comment: /home/user/sqlfile.sql is to be on the client machine, that's mean the computer that you run the command, is the directory ever exists?

Comment: @ajreal thank you so much for your comment. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. It places the sqlfile at my client computer now. But is is possible to place it on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the > symbol. Try this:

```
ssh user@host mysqldump -uusername -hlocalhost -ppassword --all-databases \> /home/user/sqlfile.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also enclose your ssh remote commands in quotes. e.g.

```
ssh user@host "mysqldump -uusername -hlocalhost -ppassword --all-databases > /home/user/sqlfile.sql"
```

That way, if you want to scp the dump to your local folder all in one, you can:

```
ssh user@host "mysqldump -uusername -hlocalhost -ppassword --all-databases" > /home/user/sqlfile.sql
```